# What gives users permisson to log onto Windows Server?

Tags: windows, windows-server-2008, remote-access, login, user-permissions

I am relatively new to Windows Server and would like someone to confirm if my understanding of the permissions required for users to logon to a Windows 2008 R2 server on a Windows domain is correct:

1. Anyone in the Administrators group can log into the server physically at the server or through a remote mstsc window by specifying their username in Logon window.
2. The Administrators group can do everything the other groups can.
3. Anyone in the Remote Desktop group can run mstsc from a client computer and see the server's log on screen.
4. Anyone in the users group can log onto the server at its login screen.

So therefore the following scenarios are true:

1. User `DOMAIN\JOHN` is in the Remote Desktop Users on `DOMAIN\SERVER1` group but not the users group on that server. User `DOMAIN\JANE` is in the users group but not the Remote Desktop Users group.

   - John can start an mstsc from `DOMAIN\PC1` as `DOMAIN\JOHN` and he will see the login screen but will not be able to sign in as `DOMAIN\JOHN` however, could sign in as `DOMAIN\JANE`.
2. User `DOMAIN\JAMES` is in the Administrators Group on `DOMAIN\SERVER1` but not in the Users or Remote Desktop Users group. He will be able to start an mstsc session on `DOMAIN\SERVER1` from `DOMAIN\PC2` as `DOMAIN\JAMES` and see the login screen and login as `DOMAIN\JAMES`.
3. User `DOMAIN\JACK` is in the Users group on `DOMAIN\SERVER1` but not in the Remote Desktop Users group. Jack can gain access to the server but only through physical access to the server itself (because he cannot get to the server via RDP).
4. User `DOMAIN\JILL` is logged into `DOMAIN\PC1`, runs mstsc, enters the username `DOMAIN\JOHN` in the Logon settings of mstsc, sees the server login screen and enters `DOMAIN\JANE` and the server desktop appears.

Sorry if this seems fairly trivial but it is my understanding from a bit of reading and it would be great if someone could confirm if I am correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## *It depends.*

The answer to your questions depends on whether the users and groups you are considering have the necessary User Rights to logon the computer.

Permission to log on a Windows Server is controlled via two [Group Policy](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh147307(v=ws.10).aspx) settings. They're both located at:

`Computer Configuration/Policies/Windows Settings/Security Settings/Local Policies/User Rights Assignment`

If you're instead editing [Local Group Policy](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc731745(v=ws.11).aspx) (vs. Domain GP), the settings are found at:

`Local Policies/User Rights Assignment`

### The two settings and their function are as follows:

### 1. "Allow log on locally"

According to [TechNet](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn221980(v=ws.11).aspx):

> This policy setting determines which users can start an interactive session on the computer.

In other words, this controls who can logon via the computer's "physical" console.  In the case of a virtual machine this would be a logon through the virtual machine management interface.

The above article confirms this right is not needed to establish a Remote Desktop session:

> Users who do not have this right are still able to start a remote interactive session on the computer if they have the **Allow logon through Remote Desktop Services** right.

*Unless* the computer is a domain-member or Domain Controller computer:

> Users must have this user right to log on over a Remote Desktop Services or Terminal Services session that is running on a Windows-based member computer or domain controller.

### 2. "Allow log on through Remote Desktop Services"

According to [TechNet](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn221985(v=ws.11).aspx):

> This policy setting determines which users or groups can access the logon screen of a remote computer through a Remote Desktop Services connection. It is possible for a user to establish a Remote Desktop Services connection to a particular server but not be able to log on to the console of that same server.

The reason a user might be able to establish a Remote Desktop session but not be able to logon to the console is because the latter requires the "Allow log on locally" right, which as mentioned above, isn't required in all cases to logon remotely.

---

The TechNet articles linked above explain what users and groups are assigned these logon rights by default.  However, by editing these two settings that can be changed. It is for that reason that the answer to your questions depends on how your server (and the domain it's in) is configured.